# is it possible to pass argument to a function in this way?

Tags: python

I am trying to pass argument to a function in this fashion

```
GroupGeneralConfig(selectedGroup = "Group1")
```

and the function looks like this...

```
def GroupGeneralConfig(self, *args)
     img = str(args[0]) + "abc"
```

whenever i execute this program it is throwing like this...

TypeError: GroupGeneralConfig() got an unexpected keyword argument
'selectedGroup'

whats wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are passing in is a keyword argument, change your method to accept keyword arguments first. Like this

```
def GroupGeneralConfig(self, *args, **kwargs)
     img = str(args[0]) + "abc"
```

Then you can pass the arguments first and then the keyword arguments, like:

```
GroupGeneralConfig(arg_x, arg_y, kwarg_x=1, kwarg_y=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want the [double star](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters):

```
def GroupGeneralConfig(self, **kwargs):
    img = str(kwargs[selectedStreamGroup]) + "abc"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `kwargs` you should define it first:

```
def GroupGeneralConfig(self, **kwargs):
```